# Makefile with foreach loop - *** missing separator

Tags: foreach, makefile, eval, separator

I am new to makefiles.

I have a large number of fairly similar directories each of which contains a makefile and some source, all of which I want to address from the directory above with an overarching makefile. The makefiles in the directories work. The number of subdirectories will grow in the future, so whatever I design should be able to grow indefinitely.

If I call the subdirectory makefiles directly I have no problem,

```
mytarget:
    cd a && $(MAKE) mytarget
    cd b && $(MAKE) mytarget
    cd c && $(MAKE) mytarget
```

but I do get a `**** missing separator` error when I try the below attached. I have used tabs, no spaces, so I do not understand my error.

```
LIST = a b c d e

mytarget:
    $(foreach var,$(LIST),$(eval cd $(var) && $(MAKE) mytarget))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want `$(eval)` there. It is wrong. The contents being passed to it are not makefile contents they are shell contents.

You want:

```
LIST = a b c d e

mytarget:
        $(foreach var,$(LIST),cd $(var) && $(MAKE) mytarget; cd ..;)
```

Because you want the result of the `$(foreach)` call to be the recipe body.

Comment: Just that one needs to do a `cd ../` at the end to get up to the main directory again.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that might be more understandable (or might not...) is to use a shell loop, not a makefile loop.  Also this results in a shorter script which could be important if you get enough subdirectories and you want to work on systems with more limited command line length restrictions:

```
LIST = a b c d e

mytarget:
        for var in $(LIST); do $(MAKE) -C $$var $@; done
```

Or if you would prefer to use `cd` instead of the GNU make `-C` option, something like this:

```
LIST = a b c d e

mytarget:
        for var in $(LIST); do (cd $$var && $(MAKE) $@); done
```

Note we use parentheses here to start the make in a subshell, so we don't have to use something like `cd ..` (which will not work if some element in `LIST` is a path rather than a simple directory, e.g. `f/g/h` or similar).

The big problem with these solutions is the error handling is all broken.  What if the sub-make for the `a` target fails?  These makefiles will not notice that.  Also, parallelism is not ideal: in all cases here only a single sub-make will be invoked at a time.

The best way to write loops in makefiles is using multiple prerequisites, not a loop inside a recipe.  Something like this:

```
LIST = a b c d e

mytarget: $(addprefix mytarget-,$(LIST))

mytarget-%:
        $(MAKE) -C $* mytarget
```

(or, `cd $* && $(MAKE) mytarget`)